# Java or php tree structure problem

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, data-structures

I have all my data in my database. It has following 4 columns

```
id  source_clust    target_clust    result_clust

1    7       72      649
2    9       572     650
3    649     454     651
4    32      650     435
```

This data is like tree structure. source_clust and target_clust generate target_clust. target_clust can be source_clust or target_clust to make a new target_clust. Is there
any php function or class that I can use to generate tree structure for my data????

I see this [MySql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) site they are doing exactly what I need but I couldn't find how to
implement that query in my data.

Thanks !

Edited

---

Is there any way in java to do it? if we have same data in array ??

Comment: Will you add more information? I am not following. You talk about source and target clusters, but where does result_cluster come into play?

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is agnes cluster output :). So it combine source and target on the basis of distance to generate result cluster. If still it is not clear, plz do let me know

Comment: or you can say that source and target are child of result but result will also be child of another result column ( MLM :) )

Comment: Can you provide sample expected output from the data you have listed? What is the expected output? The expected structure? How the data should look when successfully retrieved?

Answer (score 2):

you can download PHP tree (or even `binary tree` in your case) classes from phpclasses.org, then you can use a script that fills in the tree with the data from your database. You will have more independent parts of the tree, as you have more roots. In the case you wrote you will have 2 roots: 651 and 435.

```
[...]
$tree = new Tree();
$strsql = "SELECT source_clust, target_clust, result_clust FROM mytable";
$ressql = @mysql_query($strsql);
while(list($v1, $v2, $v3)=@mysql_fetch_array($ressql))
{
    if (!$tree->hasNode($v1))
        $tree->newNode($v1);        
    if (!$tree->hasNode($v2))
        $tree->newNode($v2);        
    if (!$tree->hasNode($v3))
        $tree->newNode($v3);

    $tree->Node($v1)->parent = $tree->Node($v3);
    $tree->Node($v2)->parent = $tree->Node($v3);
}
@mysql_free_result($ressql);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code i used to build a binary tree datastructure and its corresponding operations:

```
<?php
class Node
{
 public $data;
 public $leftChild;
 public $rightChild;

 public function __construct($data)
  {
   $this->data=$data;
   $this->leftChild=null;
   $this->rightChild=null;
  }
 public function disp_data()
  {
   echo $this->data;
  }


}//end class Node
class BinaryTree
{
 public $root;
 //public $s;
 public function __construct()
  {
   $this->root=null;
   //$this->s=file_get_contents('store');

  }
//function to display the tree
  public function display()
  {
   $this->display_tree($this->root);

  }
  public function display_tree($local_root)
  {

   if($local_root==null) 
     return;
    $this->display_tree($local_root->leftChild);
    echo $local_root->data."<br/>";
    $this->display_tree($local_root->rightChild);

  } 
// function to insert a new node
  public function insert($key)
   {
    $newnode=new Node($key);
      if($this->root==null)
        {
         $this->root=$newnode;
         return;
        }
      else
        {
         $parent=$this->root;
         $current=$this->root;
           while(true)
             {
               $parent=$current;
                 //$this->find_order($key,$current->data);
                if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
                  {
                      $current=$current->leftChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->leftChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         }//end if2
                  }//end if1 
                else
                  {
                      $current=$current->rightChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->rightChild=$newnode;
                          return;  
                         } //end if1                       
                  } //end else
             }//end while loop 
        }//end else

   } //end insert function

//function to search a particular Node
 public function find($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
            if($key==$this->find_order($key,$current->data))
              {
                $current=$current->leftChild;
              }
            else
              {
                $current=$current->rightChild;
              }
            if($current==null)
              return(null);

          }
         return($current->data); 
  }// end the function to search
 public function delete1($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
    $parent=$this->root;

    $isLeftChild=true;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
           $parent=$current;
           if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
             {
              $current=$current->leftChild;
              $isLeftChild=true;
             }   
           else
             {
              $current=$current->rightChild;
              $isLeftChild=false;   
             } 
            if($current==null)
              return(null);
          }//end while loop 

      echo "<br/><br/>Node to delete:".$current->data;
     //to delete a leaf node 
     if($current->leftChild==null&&$current->rightChild==null)
       {
           if($current==$this->root)
              $this->root=null;  
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=null;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=null;
           }
         return($current);       
       }//end if1
     //to delete a node having a leftChild 
   else if($current->rightChild==null)
       {
          if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->leftChild;
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->leftChild;
           }   
          return($current);
       }//end else if1
    //to delete a node having a rightChild
   else if($current->leftChild==null)
       {
         if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->rightChild;
         else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->rightChild;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->rightChild; 
           }  
           return($current);
       }  
   //to delete a node having both childs
    else
       {
        $successor=$this->get_successor($current);
        if($current==$this->root)
          {
            $this->root=$successor; 

          }
        else if($isLeftChild==true)
          {
           $parent->leftChild=$successor;
          }
        else
          {
           $parent->rightChild=$successor;
          }     
         $successor->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
        return($current);
       }   


  }//end the function to delete a node
//Function to find the successor node
 public function get_successor($delNode)
  {
   $succParent=$delNode;
   $successor=$delNode;
   $temp=$delNode->rightChild;
    while($temp!=null)
         {
          $succParent=$successor;
          $successor=$temp;
          $temp=$temp->leftChild;
         }
   if($successor!=$delNode->rightChild)
     {
      $succParent->leftChild=$successor->rightChild;
      $successor->rightChild=$delNode->rightChild;
     }
  return($successor);
  }
//function to find the order of two strings
 public function find_order($str1,$str2)
  {
     $str1=strtolower($str1);
     $str2=strtolower($str2);
     $i=0;
     $j=0;

     $p1=$str1[i];
     $p2=$str2[j]; 
  while(true)
   {  
       if(ord($p1)<ord($p2)||($p1==''&&$p2==''))
         {

           return($str1);
         }
      else
         {
           if(ord($p1)==ord($p2))
             {
              $p1=$str1[++$i];
              $p2=$str2[++$j];
              continue;
             }
          return($str2); 
         }
   }//end while

  } //end function find string order

 public function is_empty()
  {
    if($this->root==null)
      return(true);
    else
      return(false);
  }
}//end class BinaryTree
?>
```